# How to skip the error on duplicate indexes and continue adding documents further in MongoDB(pymongo)

Tags: python, csv, indexing, import, pymongo

I am loading data from csv file into mongoDB. First, I downloaded one document to set the collection indexes. It worked.

Now I load the rest of the documents and I have a line that is duplicated i.e. it is already in the database and is in my document. I get error 11000, how to get around it, skip the duplicate line and load the next lines?

A small part of my file, it is updated every day and needs to be imported into the database

```
    date        confirmed   deaths  recovered   region_code isolation_start       level 
0   2021-01-23  12638.0    113.0    10710.0     RU-AD       16.07.2020 21:58:11   3.0
1   2021-01-23  37509.0    1106.0   34026.0     RU-ALT      25.09.2020 10:16:19   3.0
2   2021-01-23  18698.0    130.0    16809.0     RU-AMU      21.08.2020 09:22:04   2.0
3   2021-01-23  49257.0    458.0    41291.0     RU-ARK      31.07.2020 08:45:20   2.0
4   2021-01-23  23072.0    467.0    14547.0     RU-AST      23.06.2020 14:29:27   2.0
```

Fields must be set as indices: date, region_code

My attempts

```
    def Insert(self, path=None, parse_dates=None, dtype=None, skiprows=None, astype=None):

        for df in tqdm(range(1)):
            df = pd.read_csv(path)
            data = df.to_dict('records')
        self.collection.create_index(('date', 'region_code'),unique=True)
        self.collection.insert_many(data)
     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mongodb = MongoDB(dBName='test_import', collectionName='myimport2')
    mongodb.Insert(path="C:/Users/tred1/Desktop/aggregation_RU_last_day.csv")
```

I get this error

```
BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred, full error: {'writeErrors': [{'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'keyPattern': {'date': 1}, 
'keyValue': {'date': '2021-01-23'}, 'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: test_import.myimport2 index: date_1 dup key: { date: "2021-01-23" }',
 'op': {'date': '2021-01-23', 'confirmed': 12638.0, 'deaths': 113.0, 'recovered': 10710.0, 'region_name': 'Республика Адыгея', 'region_code': 'RU-AD', 'isolation_start': '16.07.2020 21:58:11', 'level': 3.0, 'self_isolation': nan,
 '_id': ObjectId('60117910ae27c82c91526449')}}], 'writeConcernErrors': [], 'nInserted': 0, 'nUpserted': 0, 'nMatched': 0, 'nModified': 0, 'nRemoved': 0,
 'upserted': []}
```

How to add it to the exception? Probably simple, but can't find it in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two choices:

1. Iterate the data, use `insert_one()` on each, wrapped in a try/except; ignoring BulkWriteError
2. Stick with `insert_many()` and use the `ordered=False` flag.

Comment: hi, sorry to comment now. I still have a problem. When do `collection.insert_many(df2, ordered=False)` get `pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred, full error: {'writeErrors': [{'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'keyPattern': {'date': 1}...` . I can't ignore the error, maybe I don't understand something.  I will add the code to a new "Answer", please see how to add a pass to this document.

Comment: I figured it out, friend. The fact is that I initially did the wrong setting of the indexes, this was the problem, everything works fine, thanks)))